# Ramsey Combinatorics and linear order

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Prove that the following are equivalent for an infinite cardinal $\kappa$.

(1) $\kappa \to (\kappa)^2_2$

(2) In any linearly ordered set of cardinality $\kappa$ there is either a well-ordered or a reversely-well-ordered subset of cardinality $\kappa$.

I already proved (1) implies (2) - which is fairly straight - but I'm having problems on the reverse direction.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

First show that $\kappa \to (\kappa)^2_2$ holds iff $\kappa$ is inaccessible and every $\kappa$ tree has a branch - This is one of the characterizations of a weakly compact cardinal and a proof can be found in Kanamori. Now assume that every linear order on $\kappa$ has a subset of size $\kappa$ which is well ordered or reverse well ordered. Note that this immediately implies $2^{\delta} < \kappa$ for every $\delta < \kappa$ - Otherwise consider the lexicographic ordering on $2^{\delta}$ for least such $\delta$. Now fix a $\kappa$ tree $T$. We can assume that $T \subseteq {}^{< \kappa} \kappa$, $|T| = \kappa$ and each level of $T$ has size $< \kappa$. For $f, g \in T$, let $f \prec g$ if either $g$ properly extends $f$ or $f \upharpoonright \alpha = g \upharpoonright \alpha$ and $f(\alpha) < g(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in dom(f) \cap dom(g)$. $\prec$ is a linear order on $T$ so there is some $\prec$-increasing or $\prec$-decreasing sequence $ \langle f_i : i < \kappa \rangle$ in $T$. Now show that for every $\delta < \kappa$, there exists $i_{\delta} < \kappa$ such that for all $i_{\delta} < i < j < \kappa$, $f_i \upharpoonright \delta = f_j \upharpoonright \delta$ and use this to construct a cofinal branch in $T$.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I was already trying with some characterization of weakly compact; this one, as you stated and develop, seems to show the desired.

Comment: Just a note: The claimed equivalence in line 1 holds only for uncountable $\kappa$ as $\omega \rightarrow (\omega)_2^2$.

Comment: @Stefan If you think about it, $\omega$ is inaccessible and every $\omega$ tree does have a branch.

Comment: @hot_queen If you don't include "uncountable" in the definition of inaccessible, sure. Btw. I wondered if there was "a nice way" to construct for a given function $f \colon [ \kappa ]^2 \rightarrow 2$ a linear order $(\kappa, \le_f)$ whose (reverse) well-ordered subset yields a homogeneous set for $f$. Do you know of any such construction?

Comment: I think there should be one but I couldn't come up with a simple one without passing through a $\kappa$-tree.